# HTML Form element not being created in Rails 3 partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I've come across a very strange error whereby my HTML  tag isn't being rendered in a partial.

I have a erb file which contains a form and then calls the partial **outside** the form. The code in the partial looks something like:

```
<%= form_for(@new_user) do |f| %>

   <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :name %>
       ....
<% end>
```

All works fine but when I inspect the resultant HTML it doesn't have my form element. Instead it has a div that looks like the following;

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
    <input type="hidden" value="blahblahblah" name="authenticity_token">
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

D'oh. I had indented my haml incorrectly, meaning that the form was like a child element of the first form.

Comment: You have Haml views and Erb partials?

Comment: I was in the process of switching from erb to haml :-) I don't think I'm going to bother finish switch tbh as I'm hating this whitespace kENSURE errors I'm getting.